# Downgrade From iOS 7 to iOS 6.1.3 on iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6

I have upgraded iOS 6.1.3 to iOS 7 on my iPhone 4. I'm unable to test my app on that phone using XCode because I have Xcode 4.6 and Mac OS X 10.7.5. Please help me out how to downgrade to earlier version. What should I do?

Comment: check http://news.softpedia.com/news/Guide-How-to-Downgrade-from-iOS-7-to-iOS-6-384891.shtml

Comment: RIP to downgrade option

Comment: Kindly check [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/102928/31534)

Comment: I'm sure I've read that we can no longer downgrade, but I did it. I just downloaded the relevant ISPW and used Organiser's restore.

Comment: Please Let me know the steps to do it @James Webster

Comment: `just download the relevant ISPW and use Organiser's restore`

Comment: I have tried it but it Doesn't worked Please show me the steps to do it @James Webster. And where do you downloaded the ISPW give me the link

Comment: I'm not going to do your work for you, I'd want paying for doing work.  You say you've tried it, but then ask for a link. Use google: http://goo.gl/Gz4JX6

Comment: Despite what Apple says,iOS 7 can be downgraded to iOS 6    1)Download iOS 6 IPSW file for your iOS device
2)Plug your iOS device into your Mac using a Lightning cable, and open up iTunes. When iTunes has recognized your device, click on the “iPhone” or “iPod touch” button that appears in the navigation bar.      
3)hold down Alt key and click “Restore iPhone” A popup window will appear now find the IPSW file you’ve just downloaded. Double-click on it and it’ll load into iTunes.Note:Incase of error Finder->GO->type etc->open hosts in textedit and remove 74.208.105.171 gs.apple.com from hosts

Comment: link for ipsw download:http://www.iphoneheat.com/2009/03/download-iphone-firmware-files-all-at-one-place/

Comment: I have this address # 17.151.36.30    gs.apple.com
#74.208.10.249 gs.apple.com
instead of 74.208.105.171 gs.apple.com which one I suppose to delete @H.duraiamuthan

Comment: the # symbol signifies that it's commented  out..it'll be ignored by OS so you can leave it out as it is.

Answer (score 3):

That's not possible, once it's upgraded there's no coming back.

But you can always test in the Simulator in XCode with the version you want, just go to XCode - Preferences and download the simulator for that version:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the simulator- Download the iOS 6.1 simulator, because since Apple stopped signing iOS 6.1, you can only upgrade to iOS 7.

You might want to wait for a jailbreak, and you might want to google the iPhone 4 since it is a device with a special exploit, which may allow downgrading.

Answer (score 1):

You can not downgrade iOS.

You would need upgrade your MacOS X to version 10.8.4 and download Xcode 5 and you would be able to test your apps on the iPhone.

Comment: Actually you can do it via iTunes after downloading the iOS 6.1 ISPW. I ran into the same problem described by OP and "downgraded" successfully. Technically you cannot downgrade, in the correct sense of the word, but you can "reflash" the entire device, and then later restore all your data (or most of it).